# Huge strings insanity

Tags: c#, string

**Scenario**
I have a `List` containing 106091 custom objects. Each object has a string property that either contains 6 characters or 9 characters. Almost, 100000 objects have this string property length of '9' characters and remaining 6091 objects have length '6'. These strings are being written in string variable:

```
string IMDVals  = string.Empty;    

      foreach (Var Imd in Obj.Imds)
      {  
         if (i < 50000)
         IMDVals += Imd.ImdValue + ", ";
      }
```

This is going to be bound to the DataGridColumn eventually.

**Problem**
 But the thing is it fails some where in the loop and my code gets freeze without falling into the catch block.

**Question**
1. How could I come over it elegantly? How about `StringBuilder`?
2. Besides it seems, string above is huge but not that it should break the code! Isn't it?

Comment: Probably loads of GC happening. Yes, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Why are you storing the string values into 1 string (StringBuilder or otherwise)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you are two minutes too late :)

Comment: Please explain the purpose to put 50000 9/6 characters strings together to form a single string of 450000 characters (plus separators). Hope you have a solid reason to do that because no human being could make any sense from that

Comment: @Steve ... and I guess the grid just shows `123456, ...`. A waste of resources.

Comment: @Steve There's only one case where there are ample Imds in an object. For the rest they range from 1 to 9 max. Besides on clicking row its al shown in a listBox and could be edited.

Comment: What is `i` ? You could get rid of the loop if you used LINQ to filter the items, `Skip` the first 50K items or `Take` the first 50K

Comment: Client is still in old ages.. Using .net 2.0 ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating and dropping strings in an insane speed. Garbage collection will most likely be your biggest problem here.

You can prevent excessive garbage collection by using a `StringBuilder`, or `string.Join`, which uses `StringBuilder` in the back:

```
string IMDVals = string.Join(",", Obj.Imds);
```

Or:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

bool first = true;
foreach (Var Imd in Obj.Imds)
{  
    if (i < 50000)
    {
       if (first)
       {
           first = false;
       }
       {
           sb.Append(", ");
       }

       sb.Append(Imd.ImdValue);
    }
}

IMDVals = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I understand the if(first) logic, but it is not better (from a meaningless performance point of view) to use sb.Length-- outside the loop?

Comment: As I say it is probably meaningless, just wondering if testing for 109000 times an occurence that happens only the first time instead of changing a property at the end. Looking at string.Join source it seems that they follow a different approach (always add the first then start the loop), oh well....

Comment: By Dropping you mean this? : when a string is added to existing string a new space is taken and that's where previous string + new string is kept and the previous space is freed by GC. Right?

Comment: Yes. Strings can't be mutated, they are creation only.

Comment: Hmm.. Seems like I forced GC to go insane. :)

Comment: I thought of that, but I thought OP had the number in to make the loop end some time. You could indeed use `string.Join(",", Obj.Imds.Take(50000));`. @PanagiotisKanavos